# Cannot get the response made from axios call

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm making an API call using axios library in my react project. While I can console.log my response object, returning the same gives `undefined`. Any hints at where I'm committing a mistake?

```
var axios=require('axios');

module.exports={

    fetch:function(){   
  var result = axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/renx777' )
                    .then(function(response){
                       console.log(response)
                       // outputs correct response
                       return response// ex.: 200
                    });  
     // outputs undefined
      console.log(result)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning response from a Promise will be available in the next then call. You will have to do a then to get the response.

If you want to make the promise return "synchronous" results, try async await.

```
async function callApi() {
  const result = await axios.get(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well,using ES6 arrow function has solved the problem for me,but would be good to know why code i posted in the question isn't working!

```
  var axios = require('axios');

    module.exports = {

      fetch: async function () {

        var result = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/renx777')
          .then((response) => {
            return response.data;
          });


        console.log(result)
      }

    }
```